# My button affects two spans with different id

Tags: javascript, html

When I click player 1 button the score changes for both players.

Also I've tried to select `p2display` with `querySelector("#p2Display")`
and it seems that it refers it as a `nodeList` and not an `element`.

```js
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.getElementById("p1Display");
var p2Display = document.getElementById("p2Display");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;

p1button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p1Score++;
  p1Display.textContent = p1Score;

});

p1button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p2Score++;
  p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
});
```

```html
<h1>
  <span id="p1Display">0</span> To
  <span id="p2Display">0</span>
</h1>
<p>Playing to: 5</p>
<input type="number">
<button id="p1">Player One</button>
<button id="p2">Player Two</button>
<button id="reset">Reset </button>
```

My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/LrYaGb)

Comment: That's the expected behavior when attaching two listeners to the same button ...

Comment: I guess the question should be closed as "typographical error" then, not that there is anything wrong with it, but it's unlikely to be useful for anyone else.

Comment: I can't belived it.. I search and search and tottaly missed it... I use my phone to code and it's hard with small screen. And for the second Q about the selector? Thank you very much

Comment: That happens, also a joker has voted up the question, so you've earned some rep with this post = ). `querySelector` is guaranteed to return an element the first found element, if such exists. Are you sure you haven't used `querySelectorAll` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small copy paste error adding the event listener.
Also querySelector works fine for both elements. Check the code bellow.

```js
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2button = document.querySelector("#p2");
var p1Display = document.getElementById("p1Display");
var p2Display = document.getElementById("p2Display");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
/*
//p1 btn
for(var i = 0; i < p1button.length; i++){
  p1button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
 alert("clicked") });
  };
  
  */
p1button.addEventListener("click", function(){
p1Score++ ;
p1Display.textContent = p1Score;

});


p2button.addEventListener("click", function(){
p2Score++ ;
p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

});
```

```html
 <h1><span id="p1Display">0</span> To <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1>
  <p>Playing to: 5</p>
  <input type="number">
  
    <button id="p1">Player One</button>
    <button id="p2">Player Two</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The second event should be attached to the second button instead like :

```
p2button.addEventListener("click", function(){
^^^^^^^^
    p2Score++ ;
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
});
```

```js
var p1button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.getElementById("p1Display");
var p2Display = document.getElementById("p2Display");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;

p1button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  p1Score++ ;
  p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
});


p2button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  p2Score++ ;
  p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
});
```

```html
<h1><span id="p1Display">0</span> To <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1>
<p>Playing to: 5</p>
<input type="number">

<button id="p1">Player One</button>
<button id="p2">Player Two</button>
<button id="reset">Reset </button>
```